# Sandbox for Proposed Questions

Tags: discussion

## What is the Sandbox?

This ["Sandbox"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development)) is a place where LanguageLearning.SE users can get feedback on prospective questions they wish to [post](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions). This is useful because writing a clear and fully specified question on the first try can be difficult. There is a much better chance of your question being well received if you post it in the Sandbox first.

To post to the Sandbox scroll to the bottom of this page and click "Answer This Question". Please **only post questions here**.  Give the details of your question just as you would when actually posting it. Other users will help you improve your question by rating and discussing it. When you think your question is ready for the public, go ahead and [post it](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and mark it as posted here by removing the body and tags, leaving the title and a link to the question. **After a few days you should delete the post to keep the sandbox reasonably clear.**

Questions do not have to be in any particular format, but they should conform to the general guidelines for Language Learning. In particular, you can use sandbox notes to indicate your thoughts on the question, written like this: `[**Sandbox note:** your thought about this question here]`. Alternatively, you can leave your questions about the question in a Sandbox Questions section at the end.

Please review questions here by commenting and voting. If you think a question is ready for the main site, indicate this with a comment and upvote. When a question gathers enough support it will be posted. **Please avoid answering questions here.** I know it's tempting, but answering the question in a comment will clog the comments and make it harder to see good guidance.

**Please make sure you wait at least a day after posting into the Sandbox to give a range of people time to see the question and respond.**

### The Sandbox works best if you sort posts by "active" (click [here](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/sandbox-for-proposed-questions?answertab=active) to do so).

Comment: I don't think we really need a Sandbox questions on this site as we're not a site where we have extremely detailed questions, like PPCG or Worldbuilding

Comment: I think we can use a low pressure place for newer  people to try out questions. But, if we don't really need it, this post will be irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Your link to Worldbuilding.SE doesn't link to a sandbox...it's a random post about "list questions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "Sandbox" on a handful of sites for highly technical issues. That is to allow newcomers to be coached on the intricacies of asking acceptable technical questions.

For now, I don't see language learning as being a highly technical subject that would require a sandbox. That is, unless we develop a set of highly specialized on-site protocols that would need us to walk new people through our site.

Comment: Some of the more technical aspects would probably belong on http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ anyways.

Comment: @callyalater: Which is probably why we don't need a "sandbox" on this site.

Comment: Exactly. That is what I was going for. The non-technical stuff doesn't (read: shouldn't) need a Sandbox, and the technical stuff belongs somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

What is the felt need that this addresses?  Especially at this stage?

Private beta *is a sandbox*.  We don't need a sandbox within a sandbox, do we?

And even on a graduated site, I don't see the benefit.  A question that isn't within site guidelines can be put on hold, edited, and reopened.

What problem does this solve?

Comment: The Sandbox was a useful feature on Worldbuilding.  I thought it might be useful here too so I made it. That was it.

Comment: @fi12: It's possible that it would be useful. Feel free to make that case. But "here's a sandbox" doesn't make that case very well.